# Node exec function returns different results on stdout when running on Ubuntu or on Mac

Tags: node.js

I want to run the command `cloc --csv ./src` within a node app.

The code is pretty straightforward

```
exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            // handle error
        }
        if (stderr.length > 0) {
            // handle stderr;
        }
        // do stuff with stdout
    });
```

If I do run this snippet on Ubuntu, the string stored in the `stdout` variable shows something like this

```
files,language,blank,comment,code,"github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.96  T=1.40 s (141.5 files/s 13072.9 lines/s)"
20,TypeScript,100,200,300
5,Markdown,10,20,30
```

But is I do run the same command on a Mac, the `stdout` variable will contain the following

```
 700 text files.
 700 unique files.                                          
   100 files ignored.

files,language,blank,comment,code,"github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.96  T=1.40 s (141.5 files/s 13072.9 lines/s)"
    20,TypeScript,100,200,300
    5,Markdown,10,20,30
```

In other words, on Mac, I get 4 lines more at the beginning of the value returned to `stdout`.

In both cases, if I run the command from the command line, the terminal will show the same output I get on the Mac, i.e. with the starting lines.

Which is the reason for the different behaviour?